# Possible to provide a MaxRecordCount in a esri/tasks/Query?

Tags: arcgis-server

I see no mention of how to limit the number of results the server will return in [esri/tasks/Query](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/query.html).  Is it not possible?

[This query services](http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Military/FeatureServer/query) seems to indicate it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe this is set server-side via [the `Maximum number of records returned by the server` setting](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00sq0000009r000000), which is defined:

> This property specifies how many records can be returned by the server
>   to a client for any given query operation.

Answer (score 0):

No. Is the serverthat determine the MaxRecordCount.
The default is 1000, but you can change this value for each service in the Service Properties.